# Pygame collision detection, transparent border

Tags: pygame, png, transparency, collision

For my pygame project, I must detect collision betweeen various .png image that move on the screen.

I have put the image inside sprite, and the sprite inside group, then I use this :

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(perso, zombie_group, False)
```

However, sometime, my image don't touch, but pygame detect a collision...
This is due to the fact that my images are png with transparent borders.

The transparent border collide, and pygame detect this :(

Any idea to stop the transparent border from colliding ?

Comment: you can create smaller Rect in sprite object to test collision but you will have to use `for` loop to check  collision with every zombie instead of checking with group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the sprite will take the image he can't detect if it was on a trasnparent BG or a color bg, he basically is just seeing a rectangle right now.

If you are using irregular shapes and a rectangle approximation is not enough I would recommend using [collide_mask](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask)  also check [masks](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html)  it is probably what you want

**update**

Regarding performance from the [tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html) :

> There are other ways to do this, with ANDing sprite masks and so on,
>   but any way you do it in pygame, it’s probably going to be too slow.
>   For most games, it’s probably better just to do ‘sub-rect collision’ –
>   create a rect for each sprite that’s a little smaller than the actual
>   image, and use that for collisions instead. It will be much faster,
>   and in most cases the player won’t notice the inprecision.

Comment: okay thanks, I am developping a small game, is it smart to use collide mask everywhere ? How badly will my performance be affected ? There will be 7 zombie and a player, is it too much ?

Comment: Improved the answer, regarding performance maybe you are safe but it will probably be a little slow, anyway you can use it for rapid prototyping and later create some boxes on the interesting parts getting a little performance from that